# Cancel pending asyncio tasks if one completes with desired result

Tags: python, async-await, python-asyncio

The example below is purely theoretical to communicate what I am trying to achieve here.

I have a few names - Jack, Alice, Bob

One of those people have a surname - Murphy

I can make a network call to retrieve the full name. As soon as I find the person with the surname "Murphy" I am happy.

```
async def get_persons():
    persons = await asyncio.gather(
                       get_person("Jack"),
                       get_person("Alice"),
                       get_person("Bob"))

    for person in persons:
        if person.surname == "Murphy":
            return person
    

def main():
    person = asyncio.run(get_persons())
    print(f"{person.first_name} has surname {person.last_name}")
```

Of course the problem here is that we have to await all 3 requests to complete.

So the minimum wait time is the maximum request time across all 3 requests.

There are 3 network requests.

Suppose the first takes 3 seconds, the second takes 1 seconds, and the third takes 6 seconds.

It will take 6 seconds to run this code.

But we see that the second request (Alice) has the surname Murphy, and that obviously completes after 1 second.

Can we essentially ignore the other two network requests, and just return at this point?

So ultimately, the entire process takes 1 second, instead of 6.

**EDIT:**

(Code update to reflect Ajax1234's solution)

```
class Persons:

    def __init__(self):
        self.p = []

    def get_person_request(self, name):
        if name == "Alice":
            print("Searching Alice")
            time.sleep(6)
            print("Returning Alice")
            return {'firstname': "Alice", 'surname': "Donnelly"}
        if name == "Bob":
            print("Searching Bob")
            time.sleep(3)
            print("Returning Bob")
            return {'firstname': "Bob", 'surname': "Murphy"}
        if name == "Jack":
            print("Searching Jack")
            time.sleep(8)
            print("Returning Jack")
            return {'firstname': "Jack", 'surname': "Connell"}
        return None

    async def get_person(self, n, _id):
        # the process for checking if the request response returns a person with the target surname
        if (person := self.get_person_request(n))["surname"] == "Murphy":
            for i, a in self.p:
                if i != _id:
                    a.cancel()
        return person

    async def get_persons(self, names):
        print("Setting tasks...")
        self.p = [(i, asyncio.create_task(self.get_person(a, i)))
                  for i, a in enumerate(names)]
        print("Gathering async results...")
        persons = await asyncio.gather(*[a for _, a in self.p])
        return [person for person in persons if isinstance(person, dict)][0]

def test():
    val = asyncio.run(Persons().get_persons(['Bob', 'Alice', 'Jack']))
    print(val)
```

The output of the script looks like

```
Setting tasks...
Gathering async results...
Searching Bob
Returning Bob
asyncio.exceptions.CancelledError
```

I would expect the output to look something like

```
Setting tasks...
Gathering async results...
Searching Bob
Searching Alice
Searching Jack
Returning Bob
{'firstname': 'Bob', 'surname': 'Murphy'}
```

So 2 issues here:

- Why is each get_person task not running asynchronously?
- How to handle this exception where `gather()` does not allow for cancelled tasks?

Comment: If you just await `gather()`, they will all have returned before you even get to the test. However, you could wrap `get_person` in a function that sets a flag when a positive result is found and check that in a loop in your main, cancelling remaining tasks when the flag is set.

Comment: How do we cancel the remaining tasks?

Comment: Does `asyncio.as_completed` get you what you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `asyncio.create_task` to produce cancelable tasks that will be run in parallel. You can store these tasks in a list, and then when `get_person` records a surname of `"Murphy"`, all the rest can be canceled.

Edited solution, based on your full example:

```
import asyncio, time
class Persons:
   def __init__(self):
      self.p = []
   async def get_person_request(self, name):
     if name == "Alice":
         print("Searching Alice")
         await asyncio.sleep(6)
         print("Returning Alice")
         return {'firstname': "Alice", 'surname': "Donnelly"}
     if name == "Bob":
         print("Searching Bob")
         await asyncio.sleep(1)
         print("Returning Bob")
         return {'firstname': "Bob", 'surname': "Murphy"}
     if name == "Jack":
         print("Searching Jack")
         await asyncio.sleep(3)
         print("Returning Jack")
         return {'firstname': "Jack", 'surname': "Connell"}
   async def get_person(self, n, _id):
      if (person:=await self.get_person_request(n))["surname"]  == "Murphy": #the process for checking if the request response returns a person with the target surname
         for i, a in self.p:
            if i != _id:
               a.cancel()
      return person
   async def get_persons(self, names):
      self.p = [(i, asyncio.create_task(self.get_person(a, i))) for i, a in enumerate(names)]
      return await asyncio.gather(*[a for _, a in self.p], return_exceptions=True)

t = time.time()
asyncio.run(Persons().get_persons(['Jack', 'Alice', 'Bob']))
print(time.time() - t)
```

Output:

```
1.0074191093444824 #taking ~1 second to produce the desired result, as expected
```

Comment: Hi Ajax1234, I have attempted your solution. I think it's close, can you see the Edit to my question to give some follow up details on what I'm seeing? Any idea what's going wrong there

Comment: @GregPeckory Please see my recent edit, as I made a few changes to reflect your most recent code. Ultimately, you have to use `asyncio.sleep` to mirror how a non-blocking, asynchronous network request would behave, instead of `time.sleep`, which blocks the event loop. Also, I suppressed the exception from `asyncio.gather`, thus, the results from `get_persons` will return the dictionary with the target surname and the canceled tasks. I timed this process, using your original benchmarks, and the process is completed in ~1 second

Comment: Amazing, thanks so much!

Answer (score 3):

Here's a straightforward example of what you can do. Of course, in this case there's no actual service request, but just a sleep - but `.cancel()` should work regardless.

```py
from random import choice, randint
from datetime import datetime
import asyncio


async def retrieve_person():
    # this just generates a random first and last name combo
    first = choice(['Alice', 'Bob', 'Charlie', 'Dave'])
    # giving 'Murphy' a decent chance of showing up
    last = choice(['Baker', 'Murphy', 'Smith', 'Murphy'])
    # anywhere between 3 and 8 seconds for each 'request'
    duration = randint(3, 8)
    print(f'Taking {duration} seconds to get {first} {last}')
    await asyncio.sleep(duration)
    return {'first': first, 'last': last}


async def main():
    # kick off all the asynchronous tasks, without knowing which will finish
    # first and whether any of them will get us a result we actually need.
    aws = [
        asyncio.create_task(retrieve_person()),
        asyncio.create_task(retrieve_person()),
        asyncio.create_task(retrieve_person())
    ]
    print(f'Starting {datetime.now()}')
    person = None
    for coro in asyncio.as_completed(aws):
        person = await coro
        if person['last'] == 'Murphy':
            # cancel the rest and stop looping
            for other_coro in aws:
                other_coro.cancel()
            break
        else:
            person = None
    print(f'Done {datetime.now()}: {person}')


asyncio.run(main())
```

You may need to run it a couple of times if you're unlucky to see a clear example with a "Murphy", I made no effort to always include one, but the code does show that if there's no positives, the last request just gets you a `None`.

Example output:

```
Starting 2021-10-10 14:23:26.764063
Taking 8 seconds to get Alice Murphy
Taking 6 seconds to get Bob Murphy
Taking 3 seconds to get Alice Baker
Done 2021-10-10 14:23:32.762239: {'first': 'Bob', 'last': 'Murphy'}
```

Note that in this example, there would have been two possible matches, but Bob wins out after about 6 seconds and the program completes, never getting to Alice.